# How can I mimic Python's "import .. as" with code from a text string

Tags: python, import, python-importlib

I have a text string, **code**, containing the complete code for a python module. I know I could write the code to a local file and import it **as cm** with the following:

```
with open("codemod.py","w") as f:
    f.write(code)
import codemod as cm
```

Is there a way do this directly from the **code** string **without** creating a local file? Perhaps using `importlib` or `__import()__` or `exec()`?

I know that `exec(code)` has the same effect as `import codemod`, but how do I mimic the import `as cm` option?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can suggest you to first replace the name "codemod" and then apply exec:

```py
exec(code.replace("codemod","cm"))
```

But it may rename other functions or variables with "codemod" in their name.

Comment: "codemod" is not found in the code string.  It is just an arbitrary name I could use to save the string as a file and import it as a module.

Comment: This is not the same as `import ... as`. This is the same as `from ... import *`, in which case you might as well just use `exec(code)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use exec to execute the code in the string:

```py
# Read file
with open('codemod.py', 'r') as f: 
    code = f.read()

# Execute code
exec(code)
```

However, as you've already noticed, this will be running the code in the current namespace and not import it as a module but simply execute it.
If you want to have the code to be imported as a module, you need to create the module by hand and add it to the current namespace yourself:

```py
# Read file
with open('codemod.py', 'r') as f: 
    code = f.read()

import importlib.util as importutil

# Name of module

# Create a new spec for our module
codemod_spec = importutil.spec_from_loader("codemod", loader=None)

# Create a new module codemod
codemod_module = importlib.utils.module_from_spec(codemod_spec)

# Execute the code in the codemod's namespace
exec(code, codemod_module)

# Add module to namespace as 'cm' instead of 'codemod'
globals()['cm'] = codemod_module

# And from now  on out you should be all set
```

Comment: This raises a `TypeError: exec() globals must be a dict, not module`. If I'm not mistaken, you should pass `codemod_module.__dict__` to `exec()`